# Loading UINavigationController subclass from a Nib

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, interface-builder

My situation is as follows: My class `SettingsViewController` is a subclass of `UINavigationController`. That class contains the logic of its `rootViewController`. For example, it acts as the delegate and data source for two table views in that root view controller.

I have no problem setting this up programmatically. In the initializer of `SettingsViewController`, I can create an additional `UIViewController` to serve as the root view controller, position the table views in its view, and set their delegates and data sources to `self`.

But I want to load that root view via a Nib. The problem is, I do not know how to connect that Nib with my `SettingsViewController`, how to set the delegates and data sources. The `SettingsViewController` is not accessible from within the Nib. 'File Owner' represents the root view controller, not the `SettingsViewController`.

**How do I access my UINavigationController subclass from within my root view controllers Nib?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can declare a view inside your nib and set that of class `SettingsViewController` (if its a view).

or drag a view controller in IB and set this of class type `SettingsViewController`

//EDIT: so you want to present a view like `MFMailComposerViewController`. I also have a `MessageViewController` in my App which does nearly the same:

```
MessageViewController *mView = [[MessageViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"MessageView" bundle:nil];
mView.navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mView];
[masterView presentModalViewController:mView.navController animated:YES];
[mView release];
```

notice that `navController` is a `UINavigationController` which is connected in IB to a navigation controller.

Comment: This is the right answer, but I'm skeptical that subclassing UINavigationController is the right question.

Comment: This doesn't work. Dragging a view controller in my xib just instantiates a new `SettingsViewController`. Note that my `SettingsViewController` is created programmatically, _before_ I create its root view controller via a xib.

Comment: reading your comment you want to create a SettingsViewController and present it modally with a navigationBar, I am right? So what's the problem, why do you need to sublcass it? `MFMailComposerViewController` is not a subclass of `UINavigationController` its a view with a normal navigation controller (I think). I'm doing the same in my App but see the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You won't have access to objects beyond your File's Owner in your nib. You would need to setup those properties programmatically after loading your view from that nib; your rootViewController could set its tables' delegates and datasources in its -viewDidLoad.

Additionally I have to ask, why did you subclass UINavigationController. The class references warns you that "This class is not intended for subclassing." There's probably a better place for your delegate/datasource logic if that's all you need this SettingsViewController for.

Comment: I wonder why Apple recommends against subclassing UINavigationController. They do it themselves with MFMailComposeViewController.

Comment: Like any other container view controller, UINavigationController uses private APIs when displaying other UIViewControllers. For example UINavigationController sets the parentViewController and navigationController properties on the view controllers it displays. Since there's no public API for us to do the same a subclass which tries to override any of UINavigationController's behavior would be problematic. Since Apple can see the details of what UINavigationController is doing internals and choose to use their own private interfaces this is not an issue for them.

Comment: I'm not overriding any of UINavigationController's behavior.

Comment: I subclassed UINavigationController because I don't want the view controller that presents my `SettingsViewController` (modally) to be responsible for creating a UINavigationController and creating the root view controller. I figured this would be better contained in the SettingsViewController itself. (again, just like `MFMailComposeViewController`)